# Mule DWL 2.0 to convert number to word

Tags: mule, transform, mulesoft

Input : 123

output: one hundred and twenty three

how to convert number to word in dwl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer has been inspired from a Java [solution](https://www.netjstech.com/2018/11/converting-numbers-to-words-java-program.html) to the problem at hand. However this is not generic enough and solves only for 3 digit numbers. You can definitely extend this approach though.

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output json
import * from dw::Runtime


var units = [
    "",
    " one",
    " two",
    " three",
    " four",
    " five",
    " six",
    " seven",
    " eight",
    " nine"
]
 var twoDigits = [
    " ten",
    " eleven",
    " twelve",
    " thirteen",
    " fourteen",
    " fifteen",
    " sixteen",
    " seventeen",
    " eighteen",
    " nineteen"
 ]
var tenMultiples = [
    "",
    "",
    " twenty",
    " thirty",
    " forty",
    " fifty",
    " sixty",
    " seventy",
    " eighty",
    " ninety"
]
  var placeValues = [
    " ",
    " thousand",
    " million",
    " billion",
    " trillion"
  ]

var inputNum = 413


fun wtonum(inp) = do {
    var word =""
    var index=0
    ---

if((inp mod 1000) != 0)
    { a: (conv(inp mod 1000)  ) }
    else ""
}

fun conv(numInp) = do {
    var words = ""
    var calc = if((numInp mod 100) < 10) {a: units[numInp]} else if ((numInp mod 100) < 20) {a: twoDigits[(numInp mod 100) mod 10]} else {a: (tenMultiples[(numInp mod 100)/10] ++ units[(numInp mod 100) mod 10])}
    ---
    if(numInp/100 > 0.99) units[numInp/100] ++  " hundred" ++ calc.a else  calc.a
}
---
wtonum(inputNum)
```

Comment: Its not working for  values below 100 , its getting errro

Comment: Had called it out in the message along with the solution. However i have tweaked it to address 2 and 3 digits numbers